# Mongoid many-to-many relationship problem adding a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I'm using Mongoid/MongoDB with Rails and am trying to get a many-to-many relationship working.  Basically books and categories where books can be in multiple categories.  I keep getting an error:

```
undefined method `metadata' for "4e6aaec8ffb1900c19000002":String
```

when trying to add a new book and place it in categories.  The following is what I'm using for the models, form, create method and what the server is reporting.

It looks like it is trying to update book_ids and the cat_ids, but it's not getting anything for the cat_ids.  I've been trying lots of different things, but am not sure how to make this work.

The book model

```
class Book
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title, :type => String
  field :description, :type => String
  has_and_belongs_to_many :cats
end
```

The cat model (categories)

```
class Cat
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, :type => String
  field :description, :type => String
  has_and_belongs_to_many :books
end
```

This is from the form that generates the category select and allows multiple selections:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= label_tag "Cats" %><br />
  <%= f.collection_select :cats, Cat.all, :id, :name, {}, :multiple => true %>
</div>
```

The create method in the books controller:

```
def create
    @book = Book.new(params[:book])
    redirect_to(@book, :notice => 'Book was successfully created.')
end
```

From the server when submitting the form:

```
    Started POST "/books" for 127.0.0.1 at Fri Sep 09 17:30:37 -0700 2011
      Processing by BooksController#create as HTML
      Parameters: {"commit"=>"Create Book", "authenticity_token"=>"+OAIJM3NRPrUv0u1yfDEkkE2gvPQ7n0P6zPU9ZtqXlk=", 
"utf8"=>"✓", "book"=>{"title"=>"The Golf & Tennis Book", 
"cats"=>["4e6aaec8ffb1900c19000002", "4e6aaee8ffb1900c19000006"], 
"description"=>"Both golf and tennis in this book, so it's in both categories."}}
    MONGODB blog_development['system.namespaces'].find({})
    MONGODB blog_development['cats'].update({:_id=>{"$in"=>[]}}, {"$pull"=>{"book_ids"=>BSON::ObjectId('4e6aafadffb1900c1900000b')}})
    MONGODB blog_development['system.namespaces'].find({})
    MONGODB blog_development['books'].update({"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('4e6aafadffb1900c1900000b')}, {"$set"=>{"cat_ids"=>[]}})
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 24ms

    NoMethodError (undefined method `metadata' for "4e6aaec8ffb1900c19000002":String):
      app/controllers/books_controller.rb:46:in `new'
      app/controllers/books_controller.rb:46:in `create'
```

Comment: Ok, I'm embarrassed.  I see that I needed to define the cat_ids for the first argument in the collection_select (not use :cats as I was doing):

    <%= f.collection_select 'cat_ids', Cat.all, ...

Answer (score 0):

This is invalid

```
book.update_attributes({:cats => [ cat.id ]})
```

should be this

```
book.update_attributes({:cat_ids => [ cat.id ]})
```

or

```
book.update_attributes({:cats => [ cat ]})
```